# define a variable then reference it in another place

Tags: python

Trying to write a program. Where inputs & outputs names are listed at the very beginning.
After running through it will then the output be generated.
Eg.

```
### First step. import files and assign names
df1= pd.read_csv(r'df1.csv',low_memory=False)
output file name = final_output

### final step. Output files and name it as 'final_output.csv'
df_final.to_csv('output file name.csv')
```

What I'm trying to is being able to define the name of the output file at the very beginning, then reference it at the end. Not manually name it at the very end of the program.
Something in SAS would be : Define A = 'output file name'. Reference it using "&A" at the very end.
But how to make it happen in python?

Comment: `file_name = 'output file name.csv'` then `df_final.to_csv(file_name)`?

Comment: What you are describing as wanted is just the plain use of variables. It lloks like you are still to learn the distinction between variable names and strings (text-data embedded in the code).
I'd suggest you to take some minutes to follow the beggining of the Python tutorial on the official language docs before proceeding with your explorations - https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the commenters mentioned, you could include the extension in the filename and then just pass that variable to `.to_csv()`. If that's not possible, it seems to me like you're looking to use string formatting. You could try this:

```
df1= pd.read_csv(r'df1.csv',low_memory=False)
output file name = 'final_output'

### final step. Output files and name it as 'final_output.csv'
df_final.to_csv(f'{output file name}.csv')
```

Using f-strings like this is a more compact and clear way to do string formatting and concatenation to use variable in-line.

Comment: Thank you. 'output_file_name' works. just need to take out the blanks.